# how to make the ajax response to prepend div with animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

below is my code

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'load_more.php',
        data: {val:myval},
        success: function (data) {

                    $("#load_current").prepend(data);
                    //alert(data);
            }
    });
```

function is going fine, but i need animation for prepend data to div, i tried this `$(data).prependTo("#load_current").fadeIn('slow');` but there is no changes,please suggest any ideas to make it possible, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:

```js
  $('button').on('click',function(e){  //button click event is added for demo purpose you need only code inside it.
        var data = 'hiii';
        data=data+ $("#load_current").text();
        $("#load_current").hide();
        $("#load_current").html(data).fadeIn('slow');
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <div id='load_current'>
    
</div>
<button>click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$("#load_current").hide();
$(data).prependTo("#load_current").fadeIn('slow');
```

Comment: if i use `$("#load_current").hide();` then the previous prep ended data will gone,

Comment: You should enclose your data to prepend in a div which should be hidden. Then after prepending the data to your container, apply animation on the hidden div. $("<div id='newdata' style='display:none;'>" + data + "</div>").prependTo("#load_current");$("#newdata").fadeIn();

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('<p>' + data + '</p>').hide().appendTo('#load_current').fadeIn('slow');
```

[JS Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/ae9owggn/3/)